# Como ejecutar una barra de carga cuando se esta ejecutando un macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un libro [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) con capacidad de extraer datos de libros cerrados, como el proceso es lento quiero que mientras se ejecuta la extracción de los datos se muestre una barra de carga o progreso.

***PD: La cantidad de libros es variable así como la cantidad de datos en los libros.***

Comment: Que haz intentado, seria de gran ayuda que muestres tu codigo hasta el momento. Saludos

Comment: "*con capacidad de extraer datos del libro cerrados*" <-- hay muchas formas. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta aclarando cómo lo estás haciendo?. Además, "*La cantidad de libros es variable así como la cantidad de datos*" <-- Y esto es por conexión de datos o una condición dentro del script?...  Planteado de esa forma, es poco clara la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

En este enlace tienes un ejemplo funcional que te puede servir de referencia:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html

Hay que adaptarlo para que el progreso de la barra de carga esté relacionado con el tiempo restante de ejecución de tu macro. Para eso precisaría más info acerca de tu macro.

Comment: De [answer]: `Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. Esto ayudara a tus colegas a tener una idea de lo que son, y el porque decidiste añadirlos. Procura siempre citar l aparte mas relevante del enlace por si la pagina web desaparece or es cambiada en un futuro.`